# iOS: Objective-C MD5 NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, md5

I have found this md5 function here: http://www.makebetterthings.com/iphone/how-to-get-md5-and-sha1-in-objective-c-ios-sdk/

```
- (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input
{
 const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
 unsigned char digest[16];
 CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), digest ); // This is the md5 call

 NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

 for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
 [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

 return  output;

}
```

I have the signature in my header file like this:

```
- (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input;
```

There is no errors showing up in xCode, except where i try to use the function.

```
NSString *credentials = [md5 @"test"];
```

I get the message: Use of undeclared identifier 'md5'

How do i use this function?

Comment: @H2CO3: This will come handy for him, what say you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575037/what-are-resources-for-learning-objective-c

Comment: @H2CO3: did you see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392726/does-synchronized-guarantees-for-thread-safe-or-not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use:

```
NSString *credentials = [self md5:@"test"]; //[md5 @"test"];
```

If you are calling this method from the class that has method `md5:`