# IOS function handler threadsafe

Tags: ios, objective-c

The code below is called each time a scrollview scroll and if user scroll it multiple times, it crashed the code. How do i make sure only 1 code execute at a time or threadsafe?

```
 [self.cv addInfiniteScrollingWithActionHandler:^{
    [weakSelf loadNextPage];
}];
```

Comment: Please provide a stack trace and explain *why* it's crashing.  If you don't know *why*, then you need to find out before looking for answers to unknown questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example

```
- (void)_startExperiment {  
      FooClass *foo = [[FooClass alloc] init];  
      dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);  

   for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {  
     dispatch_async(queue, ^{  
       [foo doIt];  
     });  
   }  
   [foo release];  
 }
```

[Detail is Here](http://sodecon.blogspot.com/2012/08/ios-multithreading-thread-safety-in-ios.html)

Answer (score 0):

The common pattern is to use a mutex to protect a critical section of code where the structure is accessed and/or modified.

just go through this link->
[Does @synchronized guarantees for thread safety or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15392726/does-synchronized-guarantees-for-thread-safety-or-not)